# Register hot key that is already used

Tags: c#, hook, registerhotkey

**Background:**

I want to listen to a hot key sequence (`Ctrl+Alt+Left`) globally, so I'm using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
```

This works great with many other hot key sequences, such as `Ctrl+Alt+PageUp`, `Ctrl+Alt+PageDown`, etc... But a problem occurs with `Ctrl+Alt+Left`, specifically.

---

**Problem:**

On one computer, it works just fine, like any other hot key sequence, but on a different computer, where `Ctrl+Alt+Arrow` is used to rotate the screen, it fails to register the hot key (i.e returns zero and doesn't get callbacks to the window's handle).

MSDN says: *RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key.*

I would like to be able to register that hot key sequence no matter what, and if needed, override it. I would certainly want the screen to remain unrotated, at least for as long as my program is running.

Changing the hotkey sequence isn't really an option, since other computers might have other hotkey sequences that may cause failure as well.

---

**Questions:**

What is the difference between `Ctrl+Alt+Left` as a screen-rotating hotkey and a `Ctrl+S` as a saving hotkey, the causes one to fail but not the other? (maybe it is because one is a global hotkey and the second is contextual?)

Is it possible to override hotkeys entirely? Is that a good idea?

Most importantly, how can I assure that my hotkey will be registered?

Comment: The first one is global, the other local. Global hotkeys take precedence.

Comment: Does that mean I can't have a global hotkey that already exists at another application globally as well?

Comment: Not through the standard API. You'll need an ugly hack, such as a keyboardhook, a message hook, dll injection,...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just changed my approach from hotkeys to hooks.
I'm listening to any low-level keyboard press event, and getting the modifiers' states when such even fires using winAPI. Then I have full information about currently pressed sequence.

It's very long and ugly code to do all that, but eventually it is easy to work with.

```
/// <summary>
/// A class that manages a global low level keyboard hook
/// </summary>
class GlobalKeyboardHook
{
    #region Constant, Structure and Delegate Definitions

    /// <summary>
    /// defines the callback type for the hook
    /// </summary>
    public delegate int KeyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

    public struct KeyboardHookStruct
    {
        public int vkCode;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }

    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// The collections of keys to watch for
    /// </summary>
    public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle to the hook, need this to unhook and call the next hook
    /// </summary>
    private IntPtr _hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GlobalKeyboardHook"/> class and installs the keyboard hook.
    /// </summary>
    public GlobalKeyboardHook()
    {
        this.Hook();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases unmanaged resources and performs other cleanup operations before the
    /// <see cref="GlobalKeyboardHook"/> is reclaimed by garbage collection and uninstalls the keyboard hook.
    /// </summary>
    ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
    {
        this.Unhook();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Installs the global hook
    /// </summary>
    public void Hook()
    {
        IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
        this._hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, this.HookProc, hInstance, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uninstalls the global hook
    /// </summary>
    public void Unhook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(this._hhook);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The callback for the keyboard hook
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="code">The hook code, if it isn't >= 0, the function shouldn't do anyting</param>
    /// <param name="wParam">The event type</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">The keyhook event information</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private int HookProc(int code, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam)
    {
        if (code >= 0)
        {
            var key = (Keys) lParam.vkCode;

            if (this.HookedKeys.Contains(key))
            {
                var handler = this.KeyPressed;

                if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (handler != null))
                {
                    ModifierKeys mods = 0;

                    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Control) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.ControlKey) ||
                        Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LControlKey) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.RControlKey))
                    {
                        mods |= ModifierKeys.Control;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Shift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.ShiftKey) ||
                        Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LShiftKey) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.RShiftKey))
                    {
                        mods |= ModifierKeys.Shift;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.LWin) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.RWin))
                    {
                        mods |= ModifierKeys.Win;
                    }

                    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Alt))
                    {
                        mods |= ModifierKeys.Alt;
                    }

                    handler(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(mods, key));
                }
            }
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(this._hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
    }

    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    #region DLL imports

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the windows hook, do the desired event, one of hInstance or threadId must be non-null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="idHook">The id of the event you want to hook</param>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    /// <param name="hInstance">The handle you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
    /// <param name="threadId">The thread you want to attach the event to, can be null</param>
    /// <returns>a handle to the desired hook</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);

    /// <summary>
    /// Unhooks the windows hook.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hInstance">The hook handle that was returned from SetWindowsHookEx</param>
    /// <returns>True if successful, false otherwise</returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls the next hook.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="idHook">The hook id</param>
    /// <param name="nCode">The hook code</param>
    /// <param name="wParam">The wparam.</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">The lparam.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref KeyboardHookStruct lParam);

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the library.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lpFileName">Name of the library</param>
    /// <returns>A handle to the library</returns>
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    #endregion
}

static class Keyboard
{
    [Flags]
    private enum KeyStates
    {
        None = 0,
        Down = 1,
        Toggled = 2
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    private static KeyStates GetKeyState(Keys key)
    {
        KeyStates state = KeyStates.None;

        short retVal = GetKeyState((int)key);

        //If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down
        //otherwise, it is up.
        if ((retVal & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
            state |= KeyStates.Down;

        //If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled.
        if ((retVal & 1) == 1)
            state |= KeyStates.Toggled;

        return state;
    }

    public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        return KeyStates.Down == (GetKeyState(key) & KeyStates.Down);
    }

    public static bool IsKeyToggled(Keys key)
    {
        return KeyStates.Toggled == (GetKeyState(key) & KeyStates.Toggled);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Event Args for the event that is fired after the hot key has been pressed.
/// </summary>
class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    internal KeyPressedEventArgs(ModifierKeys modifier, Keys key)
    {
        this.Modifier = modifier;
        this.Key = key;

        this.Ctrl = (modifier & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0;
        this.Shift = (modifier & ModifierKeys.Shift) != 0;
        this.Win = (modifier & ModifierKeys.Win) != 0;
        this.Alt = (modifier & ModifierKeys.Alt) != 0;
    }

    public ModifierKeys Modifier { get; private set; }
    public Keys Key { get; private set; }
    public readonly bool Ctrl;
    public readonly bool Shift;
    public readonly bool Win;
    public readonly bool Alt;
}

/// <summary>
/// The enumeration of possible modifiers.
/// </summary>
[Flags]
public enum ModifierKeys : uint
{
    Alt = 1,
    Control = 2,
    Shift = 4,
    Win = 8
}
```

Comment: The main issue with hooks is that key presses get delayed until your program handled them. So it's discouraged to use it for global hotkeys.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've notices that - luckily for me, making the work threaded and passing the hook callback to the next listener right away is possible.

Comment: I would really like to see a global hotkey overrider as I am trying to find a way to override the start button.

Comment: @CarsenDanielYates MSDN says that you should not override the Windows key. It is reserved for OS use. I wanted to use it too :)

Comment: Yeah but I am making a custom shell, so I want users to be able to open up their shiny new custom start drawer with a press of the Start Key.  I don't give a rat's ass what MSDN says.  However, rather than a key hook, I think I'll just use a Shell Hook