# Sending paste message to active window's focused control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, interop

I want to intercept a hot-key (specifically `CTRL V`) which will interact with my application in a certain way. I am able to globally register the hotkey using the [`RegisterHotKey`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.RegisterHotKey) method. When I press `CTRL V` I want the focused window/control to also receive the `WM_PASTE` message. I've tried sending it trough [`SendMessage`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html) but it didn't seem to work. I eventually ended up Unregistering the HotKey, sending `^v` to the current window, then re-Registering the hotkey.

```
private static void Hook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
{
    _hook.KeyPressed -= Hook_KeyPressed;
    _hook.Dispose();
    SendKeys.Send("^v");
    _hook = new KeyboardHook();
    _hook.RegisterHotKey(global::ClipMaster.ModifierKeys.Control, Keys.V);
    _hook.KeyPressed += Hook_KeyPressed;
}
```

This does the trick, but it blocks the mouse (and the window) for around half a second. I'm also afraid it won't work in certain applications, although I don't know what example I could give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with that hook since it's impossible to understand it from the code example.

Assuming you do it for auditing reasons (or monitoring of the sort), I'd suggest to review the return value of the WM_HOTKEY message. It can "say" that the message wasn't processed, hence allowing further processing of the Ctrl-V by other logic (e.g. other hooks).
Also, i'd advise to use alternative way to re-send Ctrl-V than [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) class which has know timing issues. Did you consider posting a message instead?

I've also found alternative approach to the hooking itself by using [lower level key pressing for hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810305/register-hot-key-that-is-already-used).

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: That's a different approach than I used for hooks, but it chokes somewhere, I'll probably find a way to fix it.