# Registered hot key "PrtScn" with RegisterHotKey WinAPI function sometimes does not work as expected

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, registerhotkey

My application registers a hot key for <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> using the `RegisterHotKey()` WinAPI function.

In most cases, it works correctly and is caught by my application. But, if some applications become active on the screen then this hot key is not caught. At the same time, if I switch to another application, it works.

I observed such a problem in Task Manager, Chrome browser, and a few others. Sometimes it even doesn't work on one Chrome app window but works fine at the same time on another Chrome window.

I also observed the same problem with other applications which use <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> as a hot key, so it seems the problem is not in my application. But I still can't figure out the logic behind that.

If somebody knows what the reason is of <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> being blocked in such cases, I would appreciate if you share your knowledge.

Comment: different apps register different hotkeys to do different things? the registerhotkey function seems to associate the hotkey with a specific window or thread.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/846249/how-to-allow-applications-to-register-printscreen-hotkeys

Comment: Rather than using a hot key, consider using a keyboard hook instead, via either SetWindowsHookEx() or RegisterRawInputDevices()

Comment: This function cannot associate a hot key with a window created by another thread. You can see the remarks of [RegisterHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey#remarks).

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT In the begining of doc. you can also see "Defines a system-wide hot key.", so the remark section tells us not about functioning of Hotkey in the OS in general, but tells about how to associate Hotkey receiver Window inside the app.

Comment: Apps can hook up certain Windows behaviors and use low-level keyboard hooks or raw input to implement hotkey functionality, the system with no idea what the client code actually does.
And there isn't an easily consumable API that exposes that information. It is recommended to use hook. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810305/register-hot-key-that-is-already-used?rq=1) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

It *should* work on Chrome(unless you run Chrome with elevated privilege? no idea if it works on one window then fails on another). Failing on Task Manager is by design because of User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI). And with UIPI, both `RegisterHotKey` and `LowLevelKeyboardProc` will fail on task manager, or any other programs with higher privilege.

Please read [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations). You can either run your app as administrator,  or properly configure the `UIAccess` flag by signing the app and put it in a protected location.

> User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI) implements restrictions in the Windows subsystem that prevent lower-privilege applications from sending messages or installing hooks in higher-privilege processes. Higher-privilege applications are permitted to send messages to lower-privilege processes. UIPI doesn't interfere with or change the behavior of messages between applications at the same privilege (or integrity) level.

> This policy setting enforces the requirement that apps that request running with a UIAccess integrity level by marking UIAccess=true in their app manifest must reside in a secure location on the file system. Relatively secure locations are limited to the following directories:

```
..\Program Files\ (and subfolders)
..\Program Files (x86)\ (and subfolders, in 64-bit versions of Windows only)
..\Windows\System32\
```